# XMPP server alternatives

Tags: android, ios, server, xmpp

I'm looking for a simple messaging server which I can run on my server which will be used to register clients when they are online so they can "talk" with each other (kind of WhatsApp service but much more lightweight). The clients will be Android and iOS devices so I need a compliant client side as well.
The best solution I came up with is XMPP server but I'm not sure that this is the best choice and I'm not familiar with other possibilities.

What do you think about XMPP: is that the right solution or are there any other options?

ThX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMPP is a complete open standard IM protocol with a lot of features implemented besides messaging and presence (via XEP - extensions).

There is a really wide range of opensource [servers](http://xmpp.org/software/servers.html), [clients](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.html) and [libraries](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html) as well. So it is relatively easy to develop applications based on XMPP.

Other IM protocols are listed in this complete comparison table:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_protocols

So, IMO XMPP is a good choice to implement Android/iOS apps.

Answer (score 2):

XMPP is a good option, especially as many of the features will be already built into the platform.

However, there are many other possible approaches, depending on the actual design and feature list of your platform. You could decide to rely purely on Websockets for example to build channel based group chat. You could even decide to build your own basic protocol if you only plan to have a few features.